# How to force toString() to print "undefined" instead of "null"

Tags: java, class, tostring

I am trying have the `toString` method print "undefined" when a `Fraction` object is `null`. Here are bits from my class file and tester file:

```
public class Fraction
{
    private int num;//Short for "numerator"
    private int den;//Short for "denominator"
    public Fraction(int a,int b)
    {
        num=a;
        den=b;
    }
    //Sample method that may result in a "null" object
    public Fraction divide(Fraction frac)
    {
        if(den!=0&&frac.den!=0)
            return new Fraction(num*frac.den,den*frac.num);
        return null;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        simplify();
        if(this==null)
            return "undefined";
        if(den==0||this==null)
            return "undefined";
        if(den==1||num==den)
            return num+"";
        return num+"/"+den;
    }
}

public class FractionTest
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Fraction f1=new Fraction(8,0);
        Fraction f2=new Fraction(2,1).divide(f1);
        System.out.println(f2);
        System.out.println(f2==null);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the code produces this output:

```
null
true
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What do you think `this==null` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: If you can reference `this`, then it's not `null`.

Comment: This can't be done within the `Fraction` class. You'll need to handle it outside of the class.

Comment: Refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Your example won't run, in part because you don't provide us the `divide` function - this might help explain why you're getting the result you are.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, `this` is **never** `null`. If a piece of code calls `toString()` on a `null` object, the runtime will throw a `NullPointerException`.

So, you need to change whatever code is higher up the stack that's turning a maybe-`null` `Fraction` into a string. It's the only way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Likely it is [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-), which checks for null and either emits the string literal "null" or calls the object's `toString` method.

Comment: I wouldn't say the only way - it's the only way if the method contract continues to return `null` when the `Fraction` class represents a number in an undefined space. But that can be dealt with internally to the class - he just isn't doing that.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say without the `divide` method being provided, but this code is setting `f2` to null:

```
Fraction f2=new Fraction(2,1).divide(f1);
System.out.println(f2);
```

We can also see that `System.out.println(null)` will print `null`, so the reason your output is `null` is because you're setting `f2` to `null`.

As other posts have mentioned, you cannot call `toString` on a `null` reference: that reference has *no* methods you can call. Therefore, if you want to print something different you will need to create a function that will convert a `null` value to the desired `undefined` string.

However! Passing `null` around is bad practice. What you *should* do is define `Function` to have states in which it is undefined:

```
public class Fraction
{
    private enum STATE {
        DEFINED, UNDEFINED
    };

    //No reason to shorten private names
    private int numerator; 
    private int denominator;
    private STATE state;

    //Make your variable names meaningful!!!
    public Fraction(int numerator,int denominator)
    {
        this.numerator=numerator;
        this.denominator=denominator;
        this.state=STATE.DEFINED;
    }

    //Sample method that may result in a "null" object
    public Fraction divide(Fraction fraction)
    {
        if (fraction.denominator == 0){
            this.state = STATE.UNDEFINED;
            return this;
        }
        ...
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        simplify();
        if(this.state.equals(STATE.UNDEFINED)){
            return "undefined";
        } else {
            ...
        } //Note: you should always use braces for ifs
    }
}
```

In this formulation you leverage the object-oriented nature of Java to let the `Fraction` object itself know whether or not it is defined over the mathematical space you've defined. We know fractions are not defined for denominators of `0`, so that is one way a fraction can become undefined. Then, when you need the fraction to report on it's state, it can. Otherwise, *every other class* in your program needs to know how to handle undefined (i.e. 'null') fractions, and needs to know the difference between a fraction that is null and one that is simply undefined for perfectly good reasons (such as dividing by zero). That quickly becomes unmanageable.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that because the `this` can not be `null`, and if the object is `null` you can not call `toString` method because the `toString` method must be related to object.

But you can do that indirectly by external method or by using wrapper class to check if the passed object is `null` then print undefined

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using `this` implies that the object exists, therefore it is not `null`
 The solution would be to define a static instance of  `Fraction` class in `Fraction` class which  represents a`null` `Fraction` object. Lets say:

```
public final static Fraction NULL_FRACTION = new Fraction (); // don't forget adding default constructor
```

In your `devide` methode replace

```
return null;
```

By

```
return Fraction.NULL_FRACTION;
```

In `toString` methode replace the test :

```
this==null
```

By :

```
Fraction.NULL_FRACTION.equals (this)
```